# How to change the default settings for muPdf

Tags: mupdf

I like muPdf as it is very fast. How do I make muPdf to always open documents by default with inverted colors and fit to width settings?

Currently I press <kbd>i</kbd> to invert color and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to fit to width after I open any document.